# Can I record a video using C# by accessing the bitmap images that I set for pictureBox in WinForm App?

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox, video-recording

In my WinForm app, I managed to display the camera feed to a pictureBox.

```
using System.Drawing;
using Image = Microsoft.Azure.Kinect.Sensor.Image;
using BitmapData = System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData;

Bitmap colorBitmap;
Bitmap depthBitmap;

(...)

Image depthImage = capture.Depth;
ushort[] depthArray = depthImage.GetPixels<ushort>().ToArray();
BitmapData bitmapData = depthBitmap.LockBits(...)

(...)

colorBitmap = new Bitmap(...)

(...)

depthBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
pictureBox2.Image = depthBitmap;
pictureBox1.Image = colorBitmap;
```

Similar to I set these images to a pictureBox, can I record these bitmap images to a video file?

I could simply save the image `depthBitmap.save(...)` and `colorBitmap.save(...)` to a create a sequence of png files but not a video.

I tried using `Accord.Video.FFMPEG` and `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` but none of them work with x64 arcticute that I requrire for to build Azure apps.

Appriciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Franck Appreciate it if you could share an online resource that you found via your search. I actually did Google research before posting this here but I couldn't find a direct solution to address this question. Maybe my Google search skill is not that good. :)

Comment: type "bitmap to video file c#" that simple

Comment: Well, it is the same set of results that I got as well. I did not see a solution that runs on .NET framework 4.7.2. Many suggested using AForge.Video.FFMPEG library which is not supported by this version of .NET

Comment: If using a toolkit is an option for you, this can be done using [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/multimedia) (Disclaimer: I am a LEADTOOLS employee). There’s a C# demo with the SDK named GenerateAVI which generates a video file from bitmaps displayed using the Image property of a `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` control. I built this demo as x64 using .NET framework 4.7.2 and it worked with the SDK without any problems. If you would like to try it, there’s a free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).